# Using a loop to combine all text down a column

Tags: vba, loops, excel

Looking for help regarding writing a loop that will combine all the text values in a column while adding "OR" in between each one. To give some context, I have filenames stored in a column and I want to write a macro that will combine all those filenames separated by "OR" so I can copy and paste the string into a windows search bar and find all those files in a folder.

For example (in Column A)

```
Apples
Oranges
Bananas
Pears
Blueberries
```

In B1, the result should be `Apples OR Oranges OR Bananas OR Pears OR Blueberries`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simple example using `For Each Loop`

```
Dim cel as Range, rng as Range

Set rng = Range("A1","A5")

For Each cel in rng
    With Range("B1")
        If .Value = "" Then
            .Value = cel
        Else
            .Value = .Value & "OR" & cel
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Using simple `For Loop`:

```
Dim rng as Range, i as integer

Set rng = Range("A1", "A5")

For i = 1 to rng.Rows.Count
    With Range("B1")
        If .Value = "" Then
            .Value = rng.Range("A" & i)
        Else
            .Value = .Value & "OR" & rng.Range("A" & i)
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Using `Do Loop`

```
Dim rng as Range, i as integer

Set rng = Range("A1", "A5")
i = 1

Do Until i > rng.Rows.Count
    With Range("B1")
        If .Value = "" Then
            .Value = rng.Range("A" & i)
        Else
            .Value = .Value & "OR" & rng.Range("A" & i)
        End If
    End With
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the examples, really helped me understand. Only edit is to add a space before and after the "OR" so it is " OR ".

Comment: ah yes i missed that :). glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

While learning to use `For` and `Do` loops in VBA is an essential skill, you will find that looping over *ranges of cells* is slow, and often too slow to be useful. There is often an alternative, and in this case it's the `Join` function:

```
Function MergeColumn(rng As Range, Delimiter As String) As Variant
    MergeColumn = Join(Application.Transpose(rng.Columns(1).Value), Delimiter)
End Function
```

How this works:

- It's a UDF, so it can be called from other VBA code, or from a worksheet cell
- You pass it a `Range` object.  It processes only the left most column of that Range
- `rng.Columns(1).Value` returns the left most column, as a 2D `Variant` Array, size `n x 1` where `n` is the number of rows in `rng`.  That is, its dimension is `1 to n, 1 to 1`
- `Application.Transpose` transposes the array.  It has the added feature that when passed a `n x 1` array it returns a 1D array length `n`.  That is, its dimension is `1 to n`
- `Join` concatenates each member of the array, inserting `Delimiter` between each element.

Use it like this

In VBA

```
Sub Demo
    Dim r as Range
    Dim strResult as String
    ' Get a reference to the range to be processed, eg
    Set r = Range("A1:A10")
    ' Call the function
    strResult = MergeColumn(r, " OR ")
    ' Print Result to Imedieate window
    Debug.Print strResult
End Sub
```

As a cell formula

```
=MergeText(A1:A10," OR ")
```

Comment: plus one for the reminder. :D one of the fastest way there is.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot for an additional example.

Answer (score 1):

With a formula (assuming Apples is in A2 and B1 is blank):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),A2,B1&" OR "&A2)
```

copied down to suit (and output in last row).

Comment: Thanks, this worked - not exactly what I was looking for it may helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution. Feel free to modify the code. 
I did not include much flexibility such as count last row.
Just a basic template to show you how to use for loop.

```
for li_row = 1 to 10
   if str_file = '' then
      str_file = cells(li_row,1).value
   else
      str_file = str_file + ' OR ' + cells(li_row,1).value
   end if
next

cells(1,2).value = str_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Worked great

Answer (score 0):

One more method ..it works upto last used row in column A

Tested

```
Sub testing()
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim erange As Range
Dim str As String
With ActiveSheet
lrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
str = ""
For Each erange In .Range("A2:A" & lrow)

If str = "" Then
str = erange.Value
Else
str = str & " OR " & erange.Value

End If

Next erange

MsgBox (str)


End With

End Sub
```